# How in .htaccess enable gzip only for certain url of the site?

Tags: .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I have the site on yii2. I am using pretty URL.

---

And now I have the following settings for compressing:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE


SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:exe|t?gz|zip|bz2|sit|rar)$ no-gzip dont-vary


# Make proxies work as they should.

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

Header append Vary User-Agent

</IfModule>


</IfModule>
```

How can I enable compressing for url foo1/bar1 and foo2/bar2?